# Cette phrase est-elle asyntaxique ?

Tags: syntaxe, sujet

Dans le wiktionnaire, à l'entrée « criticailler », il y a la citation suivante : « Leur aisance à propos de tout me glace, criticaillent la prof, et ridiculisent une boursière de la campagne dieppoise qui a gardé des mots normands. »

Cette phrase est-elle asyntaxique ? Ne manque-t-il pas le mot « ils » avant « criticaillent » ?

On comprend que ce sont les autres élèves qui criticaillent la prof, mais je ne vois pas, dans la phrase, où est le sujet qui réfère aux autres élèves et qui accomplit l'action de criticailler.

Comment: C'est tout simplement une erreur de la part de celui qui a mis la citation pour la première fois sur la toile et qui a oublié un mot. Comme indiqué en fin de citation c'est un extrait d'un livre d'[Annie Ernaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annie_Ernaux) et Annie Ernaux a écrit: « Leur aisance à propos de tout me glace, elles criticaillent la prof, et ridiculisent une boursière de la campagne dieppoise qui a gardé des mots normands. »

Comment: On trouve une citation correcte de cette phrase sur internet, dans un extrait de revue littéraire: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5623688b/texteBrut.

Comment: La typo a été corrigée...

Comment: @None Bien vu ! Si vous voulez en faire une réponse à ma question alors je pourrai la désigner comme réponse acceptée.

Comment: Dans la mesure où c'est corrigé dans le wiktionnaire (deux endroits [dieppois](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dieppois) et [criticailler](https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=criticailler&oldid=27970132) la question n'a peut-être plus son utilité ? L'intérêt des réponses c'est quand elles répondent à des problèmes sur la langue ! La question a quand même été très utilise à la réputation du wiktionnaire !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an error found in the wiktionnaire. The wiktionnaire has since been corrected, the OP informed, and leaving the question seems pointless, if not detrimental, both to the wiktionnaire (not such a bad tool) and to the misquoted author.

Answer (score 0):

Oui, c'est boîteux, il y a une erreur quelque part. Ajouter "ils" comme sujet de "criticaillent" (et de "ridiculisent") serait une correction possible et plausible: *ils criticaillent la prof, et ridiculisent...*.

Comment: Le plus probable à mon avis, c'est qu'on aurait voulu écrire *-ant* au lieu de *-ent*, étant que cela donnerait du sens à la phrase et que *an* et *en* se prononcent souvent — souvant ? :) — de la même façon.

Comment: Frank @LukeSawczak « Elles » c'est tiré de la [Femme gelée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Femme_gel%C3%A9e). Un bel exemple des erreurs qui se propagent sur internet. Quelqu'un fait une erreur et l'erreur est reprise sur internet par d'autres sans vérification aucune. Il semblerait que ce soit l'article du wiktionary qui soit en début de chaîne, wiktionary ça peut être corrigé. Qu'un site qui s'intitule [La langue Française](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/dieppois) reprenne ça sans sourciller - no comment !

Comment: @None Ah, good find. Now that I reread it, the participle would yield a dangling modifier anyway.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Un participe présent serait grammaticalement possible, oui, mais il faudrait aussi utiliser _ridiculisant_, mais ré-introduire un sujet me semble être une meilleure solution.